# Using kinetic.js in IE7/8 with ExplorerCanvas

Tags: internet-explorer-7, cross-browser, html5-canvas, kineticjs

My new project uses HTMl5/canvas/JS to draw a graph. It work quite well, even in older browsers, thanks to [explorercanvas](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/).

I want to add some user interaction to it. Examples I read online tell me to use [KineticJS](http://www.kineticjs.com/), but I cant find any info on browser compatibility. Does anyone know what browsers kineticJS works with?

Comment: i've got the same question, so i've posted on theirs forum - http://www.kineticjs.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=453

Comment: I have posted on that forum as well. The creator of KineticJS responded that he won't be working on making it back compatible, and no one there seemed to have a working solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The creator of KineticJS has stated that he won't be working on making it back compatible, and there are no known solutions at this time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't there there are any  libraries like Kinetic that are supported in IE7 because IE7 did not implement enough of the  standard specification.

Hopwever, [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) is an SVG drawing library that boasts support back to IE6 and provides most all of the same features as Kinetic.js.